# Как извлечь имена из DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Всем привет не могу вытащить имена в df у меня примерно так
df

```
  **Заголовок**
Текущий счет Владимира
Текущий счет
Карта Василия
```

очу сделать так

```
  **Заголовок                  ИМЯ**
Текущий счет Владимира     Владимира
Текущий счет            
Карта Василия              Василия
```

Comment: А приведите, плиз, пример `df`, чтобы сразу можно было работать, а не набивать его. Т.е. нужно в `df` добавить новую колонку и ее заполнить последним словом колонки-заголовка?

Comment: В общем случае если имя может стоять в любой позиции и если в тексте могут быть другие слова (не имена) начинающиеся с заглавной буквы, то это задача очень непростая и решать ее придется либо при помощи поиска слов по словарю имён или обучая нейронную сеть или другим нетривиальным способом...